# How to disable a node without greying it out in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

My problem is being able to disable a `Node` such that a user can't interact with it while I'm printing it. By the same token though, I need for the overall `Node` (in this case a `GridPane`) and all of its children (Buttons and Labels primarily) to not be interactable by the user, while the print is going on.

When I write `setDisable`, it greys the whole `Node` out, but I'd like to retain the original color and state of the `Node` while its disabled.

Is there a way to do this? Either through the `disableProperty` or other means, doesn't particularly matter to me how. The key thing here is that you shouldn't be able to interact with the `Node`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would mention also to add a ProgressIndicator or an Animation so the user can see that something is going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found an answer:

From @awksp
"All Nodes in JavaFX have a `setMouseTransparent()` method, as detailed here, where the mouseTransparent property is:

`If true, this node (together with all its children) is completely transparent to mouse events. When choosing target for mouse event, nodes with mouseTransparent set to true and their subtrees won't be taken into account....`"

I then further used `setFocusTraversable(false)`, such that you could't interact with the Node by focusing it through other means

Thanks to @awksp for the help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24164911/6197978

Comment: Still won't help on touch and gesture events.

Comment: Haven't specifically tested that, but I try to recall a similar case I once had. Maybe I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Could also try setting the Node's event dispatcher to null during the print, then back to the event dispatcher that was assigned before you set it to null, after print.  I believe that should handle both touch and mouse (any InputEvent) events. 
 @see Node.setEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher)

Answer (score 7):

You can take a look on [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css):

```
/* ====   DISABLED THINGS   ================================================= */
.label:disabled,
.button:disabled,

 ... a lot more control here ...

.table-cell:selected:disabled,
.tree-table-cell:selected:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 0.4;
}
```

This means when the `disabled` selector is present, it will set the `-fx-opacity` attribute to 0.4 from the default 1.0.

> Opacity can be thought of conceptually as a postprocessing operation.
>   Conceptually, after the node (including its descendants) is rendered
>   into an RGBA offscreen image, the opacity setting specifies how to
>   blend the offscreen rendering into the current composite rendering.

You can inculude this in your css, to remove the opacity change on **any** control:

```
* :disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I indeed did try to reload  a new stylesheet after setting disable to true by using `setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1;")` and altering opacity, but for some reason it didn't alter it. I've found another solution, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

css can solve your problem use disabled property. and change background and text color.
following is the css of combobox but you can take some part of it.

```
.transparent:disabled, .transparent:disabled .arrow-button .arrow, .transparent:disabled .combo-box-base {
     -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
     -fx-opacity: 1;
     -fx-text-fill:#000000;
 }
```

for more info please see below link of css reference guide in javafx

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the time being I'll be using another solution as it's the easiest for me and seems to work without problems. If it corks out later on, then I'll be sure to come back redo the code using yours and @DVarga 's solution.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was making TicTacToe game, there I needed the button to be disabled after pressing it, but the opacity to be same as before.So I just set the opacity.

Like this...

```
 public void actions(){
       one.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
               one.setText("X");
               one.setDisable(true);
               one.setOpacity(1);
       });
```

}

I hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a particular Pane not to grayed out, you can add the below CSS Stylesheet to it.

**JavaFX**

```
node.getStyleClass().add("pane_opacity");
```

**CSS**

```
.pane_opacity:disabled .label:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .button:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .toggle-button:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .radio-button:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .check-box:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .hyperlink:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .menu-button:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .split-menu-button:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .slider:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .scroll-bar:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .scroll-pane:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .progress-bar:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .progress-indicator:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .text-input:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .choice-box:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .combo-box-base:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .date-cell:disabled > *, /* This is set on children so border is not affected. */
.pane_opacity:disabled .list-view:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-view:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .table-view:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-table-view:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tab-pane:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .titled-pane:disabled > .title,
.pane_opacity:disabled .accordion:disabled > .titled-pane > .title,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .menu:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .menu-item:disabled > .label,
.pane_opacity:disabled .menu-item:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .list-cell:filled:selected:focused:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .list-cell:filled:selected:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-cell:filled:selected:focused:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-cell:filled:selected:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-table-row-cell > .tree-disclosure-node:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .table-row-cell:selected:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-table-row-cell:selected:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .table-cell:selected:disabled,
.pane_opacity:disabled .tree-table-cell:selected:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `node.setDisable(true);` to disable the node, use `node.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1");` to prevent the node from losing its opacity.